# openSSL Key and Certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, c++, c

As far I know, in an authenticated SSL connection, both the client and server have private keys and provide their certificates (with the corresponding public keys) across the connection before establishing the secure connection. However, I'm a bit confused as there is a normal openSSL connectivity with these certificates and keys being used at server and client side but... if client key/public key generated by openssl command is created by different CA than server private key then connectivity should not happen but its not happening in the experiment I tried with openSSL.

Is it not un-expected? Is it usual to have different set of keys at client and server side by different CA ? Is openSSL generates a private key on the fly for each session and is not dependent on client ? Does anyone has any idea how these keys/certificates work at server and clent side and do these keys and certificates had any kind of relation/dependency between them..?

Comment: This question is more appropriate in this community: http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

For most SSL connections, the client *doesn't* present a certificate. Only the server is authenticated.

But if a client certificate is sent, it doesn't need to match the server certificate in any way. It's entirely up to the server to decide how it'll authenticate clients; for example, it might whitelist specific CAs, or specific certificate fingerprints, or just accept anything.

DH and ECDH ciphersuites also use public keys, but not the same ones – each side generates a temporary DH keypair, and either signs it with the certificate keypair, or sends it unsigned.

Comment: Thanks grawity for your input. But let me explain more clearly . The server has the certificate and key signed by a CA which it sends to the to the client .How can the Server be authenticated if client is not aware of the CA used by Server? What is the openSSL command which lets the server to decide how it'll authenticate clients; for example, it might whitelist specific CAs, or specific certificate fingerprints, or just accept anything?

Comment: About clients authenticating the server: If the client doesn't have the right CA cert, well, then it _can't_ authenticate the server based on CA. That's why web browsers show the scary warnings for self-signed certs. (That said, in some systems (e.g. IRC), the client is often told to expect a certificate _with a specific fingerprint_ instead of CA-based checks.)

Comment: About the server authenticating clients: Why are you looking for an OpenSSL "command"? There is no magic command. It depends on how each individual server was written. (For example, [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol).)